# Как правильно подставить значения в таблицу БД MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
   SELECT af_id, SUM(COALESCE(amount_value,0))*0.1 sum_pair_10
   FROM (SELECT arur.af_id,
   arur.r_w_uid, 
   @row_num :=  CASE WHEN @row_num_val = af_id                THEN @row_num+1
                     WHEN (@row_num_val := af_id) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                END   pair_flag,
   @lag_r_w_uid :=  CASE WHEN (@row_num_val = af_id) AND @row_num mod 2 = 1 THEN r_w_uid
                         ELSE @lag_r_w_uid
                    END r_w_uid_1     
   FROM arur, u_af, (SELECT @row_num := null, @row_num_val := null, @lag_r_w_uid := null) AS x
   WHERE u_af.id = arur.af_id 
   ORDER BY af_id, r_w_uid) t1  LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.uid IN (t1.r_w_uid,t1.r_w_uid_1) 
   AND o.status = 'Completed')
   WHERE pair_flag mod 2 = 0
   GROUP BY af_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r_w_uid) >  5
```

Как вставить результаты этого запроса в таблицу MYSQL?

Пробую так, но понятно что это неправильно.

```
INSERT INTO five_pair 
SELECT 
null,
CONCAT('Бонус за:', ' ', GROUP_CONCAT(arur.r_w_uid здесь перечисляются все за кого бонус , ',')),
arur.af_id для кого бонус, 
sum_pair_10 сумма бонуса из подзапроса, 
'RUB', 
now(), 
0
FROM (SELECT af_id, SUM(COALESCE(amount_value,0))*0.1 sum_pair_10
FROM (SELECT arur.af_id,
arur.r_w_uid, 
@row_num :=  CASE WHEN @row_num_val = af_id                THEN @row_num+1
                 WHEN (@row_num_val := af_id) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            END   pair_flag,
@lag_r_w_uid :=  CASE WHEN (@row_num_val = af_id) AND @row_num mod 2 = 1 THEN r_w_uid
                     ELSE @lag_r_w_uid
                END r_w_uid_1     
FROM arur, u_af, (SELECT @row_num := null, @row_num_val := null, @lag_r_w_uid := null) AS x
WHERE u_af.id = arur.af_id 
ORDER BY af_id, r_w_uid) t1  LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.uid IN (t1.r_w_uid,t1.r_w_uid_1) 
AND o.status = 'Completed')
WHERE pair_flag mod 2 = 0
GROUP BY af_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r_w_uid) >  3 ts, arur
```

Таблицы с кодом можно посмотреть по этой ссылке: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=79a6abef52d567543b4ad83b7fe5870d)

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать вставку правильно. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: *`INSERT INTO five_pair SELECT `* Никогда не делайте вставку просто в таблицу - Вы ещё недостаточно опытны для этого. Всегда указывайте точный список полей, в которые выполняется вставка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выполнении запроса на добавление выводится ошибка

> Data too long for column 'description' at row 87

Отключаем вставку, добавляем вывод длины получившегося значения [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=05b8809a658fa8f9bdc336f9ee8b7822) - и видим, что результат имеет длину 424, тогда как поле определено как VARCHAR(400). Следует ли удивляться, что "не лезет"?

Однако просмотр результата заставляет спросить - а зачем ДВЕ запятые в качестве разделителя-то? Если хватит одной - то всё поместится, ибо длина поля в результате станет всего лишь 324:

```
INSERT INTO five_pair 
SELECT 
null,
CONCAT('Бонус за:', ' ', GROUP_CONCAT(arur.r_w_uid)) description,
arur.af_id, 
sum_pair_10, 
'RUB', 
now(), 
0
FROM (select af_id, sum(coalesce(amount_value,0))*0.1 sum_pair_10
from (
        select 
        arur.af_id,
        arur.r_w_uid,
        lag(arur.r_w_uid) over (partition by arur.af_id order by arur.r_w_uid) r_w_uid_1
        ,row_number() OVER (partition by arur.af_id order by arur.r_w_uid ) mod 2 pair_flag

        from arur, u_af 
        where u_af.id = arur.af_id ) t1  left join orders o on (o.uid in (t1.r_w_uid,t1.r_w_uid_1) and o.status = 'Completed')
where pair_flag = 0
group by af_id
having count(distinct r_w_uid) >  3) ts, arur;
```

и вставка выполнится без проблем [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6973894fda0d22d81ac24d1b991daa98).

---

PS. Но пока что настоятельно рекомендую Вам обязательно указывать поля для вставки, т.е.

```
INSERT INTO five_pair (id, description, p_id, amount, currency, date, status)
```

PPS1. Поле `id` можно убрать - и из списка вставки, и из набора значений.

PPS2. Для поля `date` в структуре таблицы указано `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, это поле также можно убрать. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1aafdf00be9f6e5dcf49335bfc58a327). В принципе, и `status` тоже можно убрать - ибо подставляемое значение такое же, как и дефолтное.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Я понимаю что мне ещё учиться и учиться. Стараюсь прислушиваться к советам знающих. Теперь к делу:  В результате запроса получается слишком много данных, видимо я что-то изначально не так делаю. Должно было получиться `Бонус за: 25,28,29,30,32,33,35,37`(те `arur.r_w_uid`  которые связаны с `af_id = 12`  в таблице arur, а выводит вообще все uid из таблицы orders).  Также должна появиться вторая запись с такими данными: `description: Бонус за: 65,66,68,69,70,71,75,76`  `p_id: 52`  `amount: 145000` А выводит сами видите что.

Comment: @ИринаГущина Думаю, Вам надо создать новый вопрос - там дайте те же исходные данные, желаемый результат (текстом в форме таблицы), и подробные пояснения, почему он должен быть именно таким (разложите алгоритм получения каждой запятой в результате - чем подробнее, тем больше шансов на ответ, но без воды и фанатизма). Можно дополнительно сослаться на этот топик. А уж вставка в таблицу - это дело десятое.